# Why does Sedgwick assign root a new Node each time in BST?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I can't get why does root takes new value each time a new Node is put? I suppose root variable should be the reference to the first element in a binary tree.

```
public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
        private Node root;             // root of BST

        private class Node {
            private Key key;           // sorted by key
            private Value val;         // associated data
            private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
            private int size;          // number of nodes in subtree

            public Node(Key key, Value val, int size) {
                this.key = key;
                this.val = val;
                this.size = size;
            }
        }

        public void put(Key key, Value val) {
            root = put(root, key, val); //?!!
        }

        private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val) {
            if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
            int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
            if (cmp < 0) x.left = put(x.left, key, val);
            else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
            else x.val = val;
            x.size = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
            return x;
        }
}
```

Comment: It's simply to handle the case where `root == null` initially (/`x.left == null`/`x.right == null` deeper down in the tree). In all other cases, the assignment is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

`root` actually doesn't take a new value each time. The recursive helper function `put()` goes down the tree until it hits a dead end, in which case it creates a new node and returns it to the last visited node,

```
    if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
```

where it is assigned as either `left` or `right`:

```
    if (cmp < 0) x.left = put(x.left, key, val);
    else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
```

This node is then again returned as *it's* parent node's `left` or `right` and so on all the way back up the tree, until finally the old/existing root is returned:

```
    root = put(root, key, val);
```

If the tree is completely empty (if `root` is `null`), the helper function just immediately creates a new node and returns that.

---

**One key observation:**

Whatever is passed to the helper function `put` as the first argument is returned unchanged, *except* if it is `null`, in which case a new node is created and returned.